# Wordpress 3.5: Cannot redeclare wp_explain_nonce()

Tags: php, wordpress

After the upgrade to Wordpress 3.5 i have this Fatal error:

> Cannot redeclare **wp_explain_nonce()** (previously declared in wp-includes/functions.php:1858) in /wp-includes/deprecated.php on line 3176

This is the function [wp_explain_nonce()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_explain_nonce) deprecated by this version.

What can i do to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when an update was interrupted or corrupted in some way. Here's how to fix it(usually):

Use FTP client to get to your server and delete the `/wp-admin`, `/wp-includes` directories and all files in the directory where `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` were, except for `wp-config.php` and any other custom files that you might have had in there.

Then upload all files manually - download the latest WP version from [here](http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.5-no-content.zip), extract it to your computer and upload all files to your server.

If you don't want to delete your old files(which is always a good idea), just create a dummy directory, for instance `/~backup` and move all of the files and directories there(except `/wp-content/` directory and `/wp-config.php` file).

Comment: or just rename `wp-content` to `wp-content.old` and `wp-includes` to `wp-includes.old` or similar. Should be easier than actually moving all the files to somewhere else :)

Comment: Yeah, that works as well, but from my experience moving a whole bunch of files/directories is usually fast - it's unlike deleting files where the FTP client has to parse the whole file tree. This way you'll have all of the un-necessary stuff in one place :)

Comment: Mmm thank you, i would to fix without upload new files or moving files but it's the unique solution, maybe. My hosting is Dreamhost.

Comment: I just find `mv x x.old` to be quicker and safer to do than moving a tree of files somewhere else. And then if I need to get it back it's just a matter of doing `rm -rf x` and `mv x.old x`. This also means the temporary backup is right where I need it.